# SQL Server 2008 rounding and comparison issue

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do a comparison in SQL Server 2008 as part of a view. The code looks like this:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(AVG(COALESCE(monthsOld, 0.0)), 0) as AverageAge,
    CASE
        WHEN AVG(COALESCE(monthsOld, 0)) IS NULL
           THEN 0
        WHEN ROUND(AVG(COALESCE(monthsOld, 0)), 0) >= 71
           THEN 9
        ELSE 0
    END AS AverageAgePoints
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         DATEDIFF(month, table1.dateOne, table1.DateTwo) AS monthsOld
     FROM 
         table1)
```

The results are odd:

```
AverageAge  AverageAgePoints
----------------------------
71.000000   0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: where is your full sql query?

Comment: The devil is in the details for something like this and you have decided to hide the devil from us. Look at this link as an example of how to bring the devil out from his hiding spot. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The issue is dataypes http://rextester.com/RPBEP23396. `COALESCE(monthsOld, 0 )`  preserves it as an int before the average the other expression averages a decimal.

Comment: jeepers!!! how can a full be only a part

Comment: Why did you specify `0.0` in the AverageAge calculation, but `0` in the AverageAgePoints?    What happens if you use `0.0` throughout?

Comment: @TabAlleman I don't think I meant to, changing this gives me 70 as a result but still 0 for the average points

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm not sure why I put that there, I think I was expected SQL to null out an average of for example, 9, 8, NULL, and 3. However, removing it still doesn't give me the expected 9 points.

Comment: @MartinSmith That does give me the correct result.

Comment: But actually that isn't the correct result. You dont want to include nulls in the average at all. You need to get rid of the COALESCE and use CAST instead.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's a good point - I'll exclude nulls from my subquery - but you've answered my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the issue here

```
SELECT
avg(COALESCE(monthsOld, 0.0 )),
avg(COALESCE(monthsOld,0))
FROM (SELECT 70 As monthsOld 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 71
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 71) t
```

Which returns `70.666666` and `70` (Which round to 71 and 70). The first one is implicitly cast to decimal by being in a `COALESCE` expression with a decimal literal. The second one isn't so is subject to integer division.

You should get rid of all the COALESCE as treating NULL as 0 won't give the correct average. And add a CAST if you want the values treated as decimal for averaging purposes.